# Dask: Gather futures remotely

Tags: python, dask

I have a large number of futures pointing to data which I subsequently need to aggregate remotely in another task:

```py
futures = [client.submit(get_data, i) for i in range(0, LARGE_NUMBER)]
agg_future = client.submit(aggregate, futures)
```

The issue with the above is that the client complains about the size of the argument I am submitting due to the large number of futures.

If I were willing to pull the data back to the client, I would simply use `gather` to collect the results:

```py
agg_local = aggregate(client.gather(futures))
```

This, however, I would explicitly like to avoid. Is there a way (ideally non-blocking) to effectively `gather` the futures results within a remote task without having the client complain about the size of the list of futures being aggregated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your workload really suits the creation of many many futures and aggregating them in a single function, you could easily ignore the warning and continue.

However, you might find it more efficient to perform something like the [tree summation](https://examples.dask.org/delayed.html#Custom-computation:-Tree-summation) example from the docs. That case is for delayed, but a client.submit version would look pretty similar, something like replacing the line

```
lazy = add(L[i], L[i + 1])
```

with

```
lazy = client.submit(agg_func, L[i], L[i + 1])
```

but you will have to figure out a version of your aggregation function which can work pairwise to produce a grand result. Presumably, this would result in a rather large number of futures in-play on the scheduler, which may cause additional latency, so profile to see what works well!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably do this within a worker:

```py
>>> def f():
...     client = get_client()
...     futures = client.map(lambda x: x + 1, range(10))  # spawn many tasks
...     results = client.gather(futures)
...     return sum(results)

>>> future = client.submit(f)
>>> future.result()
```

This example is lifted directly from the docs on [get_client](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.get_client)

Comment: beat me, and with a different solution!

Comment: I like yours better!